De Moivre's Theorem | Evaluate the following power: $(\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt{5}}}{4}i)^{9}$
So I've been trying to solve a problem from a homework in a couple few days about the topic but I'm not so sure if I'm going correctly.
The problem is simple and directly. Evaluate the following power:
$$
\biggl( \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt{5}}}{4}\,i \biggr)^9
$$
I know that $r = |z| = 1$ but the argument $\theta$ is going to be really weird if I keep going like $a = r\cos(\theta)$ or $b = r\sin(\theta)$.
If someone could help me with this next step, or give me a different view, would appreciate. :)

now that you have edited -- check out the ratios for $\frac{\pi}5$.. its considered a "standard angle" by some

It seems that $\theta= \dfrac{\pi}5$, see Approach zero's search results

I think to should identity the angle.

@Sahaj There's lots of lovely geometry in the pentagon. OTOH, I wouldn't expect most people to instantly recognise its trig ratios, unless they've worked with them extensively. I suppose the golden ratio is a big clue, though. ;)

Here, we have:
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}{\sqrt5+1}$$
where, we can find that:
$$1-\tan^2\theta=1-\frac{10-2\sqrt5}{6+2\sqrt5}=\frac{2\sqrt5-2}{3+\sqrt5}$$
And then, from here, we can get:
$$\tan2\theta=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}=\frac{(3+\sqrt5)\left(\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}\right)}{(\sqrt5-1)(\sqrt5+1)}$$
$$\tan2\theta=\frac{(3+\sqrt5)\left(\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}\right)}4$$
And again, we shall try to find $\tan3\theta$ to get:
$$\tan3\theta=(\tan\theta)\frac{3-\tan^2\theta}{1-3\tan^2\theta}$$
To calculate this, we have from the calculator:
$$3-\tan^2\theta=3-\frac{10-2\sqrt5}{6+2\sqrt5}=2\sqrt5-2$$
$$1-3\tan^2\theta=1-\frac{15-3\sqrt5}{3+\sqrt5}=-14+6\sqrt5$$
and finally:
$$
\tan 3\theta=(\tan\theta) \frac{2\sqrt5-2}{6\sqrt5-14}=\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}{\sqrt5+1} (-2-\sqrt5)
$$
$$\tan 3\theta=\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}{(\sqrt5+1)(\sqrt5-1)} (-2-\sqrt5)(\sqrt5-1)$$
$$\tan 3\theta=-\frac{(3+\sqrt5) \left(\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}\right)}4$$
And from here, we can see that:
$$\tan2\theta=-\tan3\theta=\tan(\pi-3\theta)\Rightarrow 5\theta=\pi$$
$$\theta=\frac{\pi}5$$
Now, if we continue:
$$(re^{i\theta})^9=r^9e^{i9\theta}$$
to get your job done.

Let $\begin{cases}c=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}4\\s=\dfrac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}4\end{cases}\quad$ and $\ z=c+is$
Squaring gives :
$\quad c^2=\frac{1+5+2\sqrt{5}}{16}=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}8\qquad s^2=\frac{10-2\sqrt{5}}{16}=\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}8$
And we notice $c^2+s^2=\frac 88=1$ so $|z|=1$ and $c,s$ are cosine and sine.
Instead of calculating $\arg(z)$, I propose to find the polynomial cancelling $z$.
Notice that $c^2=\frac 14+\frac c2$ and $s^2=\frac 34-\frac c2$
$\begin{align}z^2&=c^2-s^2+2ics=c-\tfrac 12+2ics=c-\tfrac 12+2c(z-c)=c-\tfrac 12+2cz-2c^2\\&=(c-\tfrac 12-2(\tfrac 14+\tfrac c2))+2cz = -1+2cz \end{align}$
We get :
$$z^2=-1+(\tfrac{\sqrt{5}}2+\tfrac 12)z$$
We can isolate the square root and square again :
$\frac 54z^2 = (z^2+1-\frac z2)^2 = z^4+1+\frac {z^2}4+2z^2-z-z^3=z^4-z^3+\frac 94z^2-z+1$
And we get $$z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1=0$$
Since $z\neq -1$ we can multiply by $(1+z)$ to get
$$1+z^5=0$$
Therefore $z^{10}=(z^5)^2=(-1)^2=1\ $ and since $\ |z|^2=\bar zz=1$

Then $z^9=\frac 1z=\bar z=c-is$

